# Specialization of member function template after instantiation error, and order of member functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The following bit of code fails to compile on gcc 4.5.3

```
struct Frobnigator
{
    template<typename T>
    void foo();

    template<typename T>
    void bar(); 
};

template<typename T>
void Frobnigator::bar()
{
}

template<typename T>
void Frobnigator::foo()
{
    bar<T>();
}

template<>      // error
void Frobnigator::foo<bool>()
{
    bar<bool>();
}

template<>
void Frobnigator::bar<bool>()
{
}

int main()
{
}
```

Error message: `specialization of ‘void Frobnigator::bar() [with T = bool]’ after instantiation`. I finally resolved this problem by having the specialization of `Frobnigator::bar<bool>()` appear before `Frobnigator::foo<bool>()`. Clearly the order in which the methods appear matter.

Why then is the  following lite version of the above code, in which the  the specialization of `bar` appears after the generic version, valid ?

```
struct Frobnigator
{
    template<typename T>
    void foo();
};

template<typename T>
void Frobnigator::bar()
{
}

template<>
void Frobnigator::bar<bool>()
{
}

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your first code is not correct by standard.

n3376 14.7.3/6

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that **specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation
> to take place**, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

In your case - implicit instantiation of `bar` function with type `bool` is required by its usage in `foo<bool>`, before explicit specialization declaration.

Comment: I found compiling with clang gave me a much better error message and showed me where the first use was.  So helpful in my case.

Answer (score 5):

> Clearly the order in which the methods appear matter.

Indeed; as is usually the case in C++, you can't use something before it's declared, and this applies to explicit template specialisations as well as most other things.

Using `bar<bool>` (by calling it from `foo<bool>`) without a previous declaration of an explicit specialisation causes that specialisation to be instantiated from the generic template, if it hasn't already been. You'll need at least a declaration of the explicit specialisation to prevent that.

> Why is this the case, considering that the specialization of bar appears after the generic version in the following lite version of the above code

The second example differs by not instantiating `foo<bool>` at all. The issue isn't that the specialisation is declared after the generic template (which must be the case), but that it's declared after that specialisation has already been instantiated.

Comment: I think this is silly and shoud be a addressed. It defeats the plan of declare first and define later. Cpp is doing too much things implicitly. It should see my function call, and link the appropriate compiled function. Note that an explicit declaration dont solve problem.