# Error when compiling/mexing imrender function with OS X in Matlab

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, mex

I am trying to use a specific function in Oliver Woodford's imrender_v2.4.zip (http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ojw/software.htm) in Matlab, specifically the vgg_qpbo function.

The related files are supposed to recognize that a mex-file does not exist and compile one.

However, after running startup.m and trying something like

`>> vgg_qpbo(1,1,1)`

I get

```
Warning: Missing MEX-file: vgg_qpbo. Will attempt to compile and run. 
 > In vgg_mexcompile_script at 25
  In vgg_qpbo at 84 
mex -O -I"/Users/.../imrender/vgg" "-Iqpbo/" "vgg_qpbo.cxx" "qpbo/QPBO.cpp" "qpbo/QPBO_maxflow.cpp" "qpbo/QPBO_extra.cpp" "qpbo/QPBO_postprocessing.cpp"
Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
In file included from /Users/.../imrender/vgg/vgg_qpbo.cxx:11:
In file included from qpbo/QPBO.h:116:
qpbo/block.h:124:56: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
                            if (!next) { if (error_function) (*error_function)("Not enough memory!"); exit(1); }
                                                                               ^
qpbo/block.h:223:56: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
                    if (!first) { if (error_function) (*error_function)("Not enough memory!"); exit(1); }
                                                                        ^
2 warnings generated.

ERROR while compiling vgg_qpbo
Error using vgg_mexcompile_script (line 30)
Unable to compile vgg_qpbo.

Error in vgg_qpbo (line 84)
vgg_mexcompile_script; % Compilation happens in this script
```

I have been trying to figure out what is the problem.
The main suspect is the Mac OS X (Yosemite 10.2) I am running, as it is compilable on a Linux version (do not know which, but I could find out if you think it is relevant) my supervisor used. It is not exclusive to my computer as we tried it on another mac with the exact same result.

I believe the warnings are ignorable as they are just warnings (I am not savvy in C++, but I gathered that it is a relatively new warning, but should not affect the compilation itself).

I have also tried figuring out where in the scripts the error occurs, but the mexing-part is definitely starting, and further than that I do not feel comfortable to go.

I have mexed other scripts on this computer before and I can run for example

```
>> mex -setup
```

without a hitch.

So does anyone know what the problem might be? And thank you for your time!

I am running Matlab R2014B by the way.

**EDIT**

So I followed lilbill39's suggestion and put a breakpoint at the line that calls the mexing (line 74 in vgg_mexcompile) and then ran

```
eval(cmd)
```

from the command line.

This resulted in 36 new warnings, 23 notes and 4 errors.

The errors are all alike but on different lines:

```
qpbo/instances.inc:19:29: error: explicit specialization of 'get_type_information' after instantiation
    inline void QPBO<int32_t>::get_type_information(char*& type_name, char*& type_format)
```

After each of these 4 errors the same type of note follows:

```
/Users/.../imrender/vgg/qpbo/QPBO.cpp:277:3: note: implicit
instantiation first required here
            get_type_information(type_name, type_format);
            ^
```

There was one other kind of note (29 of these in total):

```
qpbo/instances.inc:15:16: note: in instantiation of member function  'QPBO<float>::Save' requested here
template class QPBO<float>;
           ^
```

With different classes within the arrows.

Most of the warnings were the same

```
conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
```

-warnings as before. Whereas some were of the type

```
format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long long'
```

with mixed number formats.

So it would seem that an "implicit instantiation" is needed in four places in the QPBO.cpp-file (assuming all warnings can be ignored yet again). With a quick google search I gathered that it has something to do with the "linking" of the files, however it is getting late and will have to continue searching tomorrow. More help until then would of course be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That rather suggests your compiler options are set for (or defaulting to) the C++11 standard - given that it's older code (and the amount of changes to the C++ language over various standards) you almost certainly want to compile it as something older. For that part, at least, the more specific question is then how to get mex to configure whatever compiler this is to compile as, say, C++98.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint at line 74 of `vgg_mexcompile.m` that does `eval(cmd);`. When the debugger hits that point, run `eval(cmd)` at the MATLAB command prompt and see what the real error is. `vgg_mexcompile` looks to be swallowing the error with that `try...catch`

Comment: Alright, thank you for the comments! I'll wait a while to try and set up an older compiler, but I'll come back to that if it seems to be the only way out later. I'll add the result of the debug compiling to the question, great tip by the way!

Comment: You need to at least _declare_" the explicit specialization before the instantiations.  Have you modified or misplaced a header?

Comment: No, I haven't modified anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't verify this as a solution for you because it compiles fine on my machine with VS2012, but my suggestion would be to move the instantiations below the declarations and definitions of the specializations.  Edit instances.inc and move the following lines:

```
// Instantiations
template class QPBO<int32_t>;
template class QPBO<int64_t>;
template class QPBO<float>;
template class QPBO<double>;
```

to the bottom of the file (below the specializations).

See [this answer for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112309/2778484).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this worked perfectly! And I'm actually going to have to learn some C++, so hopefully that answer will make sense to me after that.

Comment: @JohanPI Great!  I'm not really sure why my compiler didn't have any trouble as it does seem illegal.  Perhaps it runs multiple analysis passes of the code and found the specialization after the instantiations and just decided to go with it.  Feel free to come back and upvote too when you get a bit more rep.  Thanks!