# something confusing about class template partial specialization & class member specialization

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Here I define a class template Foo, specialize its member function, and then supply a partial specialization for that class:

```
// this is Foo_0
template<typename T, typename S>
class Foo {
public:
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "Foo_0\n";
    }
    template<typename R>
    void bar(R) {
        std::cout << "I'm from Foo_0\n";
    }
};
template<>
template<>
void Foo<double, int>::bar(double) {
    std::cout << "Now I'm specialized!\n";
}

// this is Foo_1
template<typename T>
class Foo<T, int> {
public:
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "Foo_1\n";
    }
};
```

And I instantiate Foo on VS2015 like this:

```
Foo<double, int> f;
f();
```

Surprisingly, f() prints "Foo_0", which means the partial specialized template Foo_1 isn't chosen. 
What's even stranger, when I comment the specialization of Foo::bar(double), f() prints "Foo_1"!

Then I test this:

```
Foo<int, int> f;
f();
```

This time, f() also prints "Foo_1", the class specialization is applied.

So it seems that the specialization of member bar() do influence the application of partial specialization of the class template. Is that true? Why does it work like this?

Comment: Try moving the explicit function template specialization below the partial class template specialization.

Comment: @Kerrek SB When I move it, the compiler complains that "class Foo doesn't have member Bar", it seems that bar(double) is considered as a member of Foo_1.

Comment: gcc succeeds to diagnose the problem (contrary to clang) [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed9bb1a4e9682621). (`error: partial specialization of 'class Foo<T, int>' after instantiation of 'class Foo<double, int>' [-fpermissive]`)

Comment: Related to [specialization-of-member-function-template-after-instantiation-error-and-order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112148/specialization-of-member-function-template-after-instantiation-error-and-order)

Comment: The explicit specialization of `bar` cause an implicit instantiation of `Foo<double, int>`, which is a better match than `Foo<T, int>` so you get `Foo_0` with the specialized `bar` and `Foo_1` when you comment it out.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, so it's because class Foo is already implicitly instantiated as Foo<double, int> inside the specialization of bar(), thus Foo_2 can't be applied on Foo<double, int>, right?

Comment: @TemplateRex Thanks, now I understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicit specialization of `Foo<double, int>::bar`

```
template<>
template<>
void Foo<double, int>::bar(double) {
    std::cout << "Now I'm specialized!\n";
}
```

causes an implicit instantiation of `Foo<double, int>`. This is a better match than the partially specialized `Foo<T, int>`, so you get `Foo_0` instead of `Foo_1`, unless you comment out the specialization of `bar`.

What you could do is to move `bar(double)` into the general class template `Foo<T, S>` as a regular overloaded member function

```
template<class T, class S>
class Foo {
    // as before

    void bar(double) {
        std::cout << "Now I'm overloaded!\n";
    }
};
```

Now you will get `Foo_1`, [**live example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Qqufxt9cj6ds3RqN). Note that you won't be able to call `Foo<double, int>::bar(double)` anymore. If you want that, then you need to add a `bar` member to the partial specialization `Foo<T, int>` as well.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful