# Template specialisation unable to resolve this-context method without forward-declaration

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have a template class which takes on roughly the form of the given code below.

```
template <int index = 0>
struct Thing {
  void Hello();
  void Greet(const char *name);
};
```

Which works just fine for its purpose, until one decides to try and call methods on itself. Say that you define the methods as shown below.

```
template <>
void Thing<>::Greet(const char *name) {
  Hello();
  printf(", %s!\n", name);
}

template <>
void Thing<>::Hello() {
  printf("Hello");
}
```

Then calling `Greet()` yields an explicit specialisation error, which I find weird. The compiler ought to know all of the methods of `this` by its interface declaration, but for some reason it cannot resolve it in this case. This can be solved in one of two ways; either you must forward-declare any methods called on yourself, or make sure the methods are defined in an order that ensures that the ones you call are defined beforehand.

This issue is really annoying, because I have provided an interface declaration, and any specialisation of the template ought to conform to that same interface, so I really don't see why the compiler complains about this — is there any way to fix the issue without polluting the code with forward-declarations of each method, or having to order methods in a particular manner?

I hope you have some great ideas for solving the issue in a better way. Thank you in advance!

For ease of reproducing the issue, here's a snippet that will call the offending method.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  Thing<0> thing_with_zero;
  thing_with_zero.Greet("World");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need **specialization**? (You don't provide generic `template <int index> void Thing<index>::Hello()`...)

Comment: Yes, yes I do. As stated this is just a simplified version of the actual class, that exhibits the same problem. The point of it is that the specialisation argument is variable for a given compile configuration, so the empty <> given are filled out by some compiler definitions.

Comment: The thing is that the call to `Hello();` is first seen as the generic call, but then you specialize it. Maybe specialize the whole class and provide definitions within the class would fit your needs.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide a small example of what you mean I should change? It sounds like you have something worth trying out :) The methods must remain non-templated, for other reasons.

Comment: Related question [Specialization of member function template after instantiation error, and order of member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112148)?

Comment: @t.niese Yes, I couldn't find any related subjects before posting, but yes, that is exactly the same sort of issue!

Comment: The first suggestion @Jarod42 actually might be worth exploring a bit. I have it working with providing the generic as the default, and specialise when needed. So that might be the way forward.

Comment: `and any specialisation of the template ought to conform to that same interface`, `Thing<0>` and `Thing<1>` are two completely different types they don't need to share anything.

Comment: "because I have provided an interface declaration, and any specialisation of the template ought to conform to that same interface" do you refer to the code you posted or to something in your actual code not included here? Asking, because in the code you posted, what t.niese said, different specializations are completely different types and dont have necessarily anything in common

Comment: You are correct, I am probably assuming some knowledge from the "actual" class. There are many possible values of `index`, but only one will be valid. The intent is that the base declaration is shared for each `Thing`. That is, there are no specialisations specified — just the generic one, as you see above.

Comment: How about `if constexpr` inside the definition to avoid specialization?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have support for that with our compiler. But yes, that is what it is trying to achieve :)

Comment: For your case, regular `if` might work and let compiler does the optimization to remove dead code.

Comment: You have too much faith in the compiler :D We're working on an embedded system, and the compiler is reeeally bad at optimising such things. That is the entire reason for this monstrous construction, to help the compiler :P

Ideally this whole exercise could've been avoided, had the compiler done its job right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might specialize the whole class to ensure that specialization are seen:

```
// Primary template
// generic one
template <int index = 0>
struct Thing {
    void Hello() {/*..*/}
    void Greet(const char *name) {/*..*/}
};

// Specialization for index == 0
template <>
struct Thing<0> {
    void Greet(const char *name) {
        Hello();
        printf(", %s!\n", name);
    }
    void Hello() {
        printf("Hello");
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you might drop specialization with the help of `if constexpr` (C++17):

```
template <int index = 0>
struct Thing
{
    void Greet(const char *name) {
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            Hello();
            printf(", %s!\n", name);
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
    void Hello() {
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            printf("Hello");
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Oooh, I see what you mean. Hm, no, unfortunately I think that breaks the ease-of-use that it is intended for. But yes, that definitely could have solved the problem, and also gave me another idea for some improvement. Good shot, thanks!

Comment: Not clear to me what is your "ease-of-use". You have to declare thing before using it in one way or other.

Comment: Yes, but this particular thing is supposed to have many variations, so declaring ones with a shared interface is preferable :)

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is inherently unsolvable, given the answer in the related question. So, I'm gonna take your inputs and see if I can revise the thing in a way that can fulfil its function in a similar manner, and then mark the question as answered by this entry :)